# undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader`

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#else
...
#endif
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <box2d/box2d.h>
```

Everything, like `glewInit, glDrawArrays...`, worked fine before I started using `glCreateShader, glShaderSource, glCompileShader, glAttachShader, glLinkProgram` Now, the compiler shows me these errors:

```
>g++ -std=c++14 b.cpp -lbox2d -lmingw32 -lsdl2main -lsdl2 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -o b.exe

b.cpp:(.text+0xcff): undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
b.cpp:(.text+0xd50): undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
b.cpp:(.text+0xd78): undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
b.cpp:(.text+0xd88): undefined reference to `__glewCreateProgram'
b.cpp:(.text+0xd95): undefined reference to `__glewAttachShader'
b.cpp:(.text+0xdaf): undefined reference to `__glewLinkProgram'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using glew 1.13.0 Win32 and SDL2-i686-w64-mingw32. What should I do?

Comment: Did you forget to actually link with GLEW?

Comment: @immibis What is to actually link with GLEW? Isn't -lglew32 linking glew?

Answer (score 3):

You may have to link against `-lGLEW` instead of `-lglew32` since you are using MinGW.

Comment: -lGLEW option works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this did the job.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "glew.c"   //I've brought glew.c from glew source folder
#else
...
#endif
...
```

Comment: Unless you really know what you're doing, you sould *never* include C files directly.